# It's not working -tried many ways still issues exists the same

Tags: postgresql

Mine is Postgresql 13 version and could see some strange issues when I use Alter default privileges,let Me explain.

I have logged in with Postgres user and created database called testdb with schema name called lab and 2 tables called emp1 & emp2

and have created user test under the lab.testdb with select permission (this has give via role) -- the complete steps is as follows.

```
CREATE ROLE read_role;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA lab TO read_role;
CREATE USER test WITH PASSWORD 'xxxxxx';
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE testdb TO test;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA lab TO test;
GRANT read_role TO test;
```

Say have created first table called "emp1" under the lab.testdb,further I have connected to "testdb" using user which I created called "test" -

using that user I'm able to query the table called emp1 sucessfully.

Now the issue comes, say have created another table called "emp2" using the postgres as the user in the "lab.test" .

So if I use

```
select * from emp2
```

under the "test" user context Iam getting the error message called-

```
ERROR:  permission denied for table emp2
```

so there are manythings shows that if we use Alter default privileges- will fix all the future tables too so I have used below exuected under "postgres"

```
 ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE read_role IN SCHEMA lab GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read_role;
```

Post the exuection Iam getting same error messages, but If I Try-

```
 GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA lab TO read_role;
```

its fixing again.

but the same issues occurring if I created other new tables try same way it's not working at all-- Need some one help to resolve ,where am I missing or to fix.

Comment: Don't keep asking [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76786990/6464308) over again. `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` only affects objects *created* by the role specified in the `FOR ROLE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Grant the “test” user select privileges on all tables in the lab schema.
`GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA lab TO test;`

Comment: I have tried already...That will just does the refresh and works, but again for new tables you need to keep doing same way- thats not good at all.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly assign “read_role” as a member of “test” using `ALTER USER test IN ROLE read_role;` you can verify this using `\du`.

Comment: That role is already mapped again no need to Alter .

Comment: Can someone assist Me and you can also test and see- let me where am I doing mistake or anything need to consider..please advise and appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but this works fine for me.

```
CREATE ROLE read_role LOGIN PASSWORD 'read_role';

grant all privileges on schema lab  to read_role;

grant select on all tables in schema lab  to read_role;
```

Login with the role `read_role` and try once.

Comment: Does this works for user level,why I need to create a role with login password ...Im confused here(sorry to say)  but I wanted the way that I mentioned ..so..Please assist Me further as Iam new and learning..   also grant all privileges on schema lab  to read_role;  -- My intention to give select permission only.

Comment: Not sure why this question is closed because none of other questions which were answered not solving My question here...please re open this question to forum please.